# Ayuda para la creación de dinámica de botones paginado JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

estoy en pleno desarrollo del proyecto de una aplicación web y me he topado con un problema sencillo pero que no logro resolver:

- Mi aplicación muestra los eventos recogidos en una BD externa. Para evitar que me aparezca una tabla interminable, cuando la BD empieza a tener ya un tamaño considerable, he optado por dividir la tabla en distintas páginas y que estas muestren únicamente 5 eventos/página.

  - Soy capaz de sacar los 5 eventos por cada página, el problema es que cuando quiero hacer que se me creen los botones de paginado de forma dinámica (20 eventos -> 4 botones,  23 eventos -> 5 botones, etc) me aparece la línea html de los mismos entre "" por lo que no me reconoce los "li" la página html.

Dejo imagen:  https://image.prntscr.com/image/9G0wSc9GTIC6I_jqsJsAAw.png

Dejo código de parte del HTML:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="pull-left position" aria-label="Page navigation" id="div1">
        <ul id="ul_pager" class="pager">
            <li><a href="#" onclick="page(0)">1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table id="tableEvents"></table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Dejo también el JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var i = 1;
        var j = i + 1;
        var ul = document.getElementById("ul_pager");

        while (i < tpage) {
            ul.append('<li><a href="#" onclick="page(' + i + ')"> ' + j + '</a></li>');
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    });
```

Aclaro que tpage es una variable (declarada en otro JS) que contiene el número de botones de paginado que se deben crear y funciona correctamente.

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda, un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en el método `append` no estás añadiendo elementos ´li´ si no cadenas con el código html del elemento `li`.

En cualquier caso, si utilizas jQuery, ¿por qué no lo utilizas luego para manipular el DOM?:

```js
var tpage = 7;

$(document).ready(function () {
      var i = 1;
      var j = i + 1;
      var ul = $("#ul_pager");

      while (i < tpage) {
          ul.append($('<li><a href="#" onclick="page(' + i + ')"> ' + j + '</a></li>'));
          i++;
          j++;
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="pull-left position" aria-label="Page navigation" id="div1">
      <ul id="ul_pager" class="pager">
          <li><a href="#" onclick="page(0)">1</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
          <table id="tableEvents"></table>
      </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, Asier! Se hace complicado a veces utilizar un lenguaje al que no estás habituado y no sabes demasiado.

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando el método nativo [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) en lugar del de [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/append/): Uno inserta texto mientras que el segundo interpreta el texto que introduzcas.
Te pongo la solución con jQuery porque veo que ya lo estás usando; la solución con métodos nativos incluiría crear el elemento con `document.createElement` y luego insertarlo con `appendChild` en lugar de con `append`

```js
let tpage=4;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;
    var j = i + 1;
    var ul = document.getElementById("ul_pager");

    while (i < tpage) {
        $('#ul_pager').append('<li><a href="#" onclick="page(' + i + ')"> ' + j + '</a></li>');
        i++;
        j++;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul_pager" class="pager">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="page(0)">1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", dom);

function dom(){
var ul = document.createElement("UL"),
    li = 20, i = 1;
    for(;i<=li;i++){
    var newLi = document.createElement("li");
    newLi.id = i;
    newLi.innerHTML = `Tengo id: ${i}`;
    ul.appendChild(newLi);
    document.body.appendChild(ul);
    }
}
```